# Why is this SQL connection in my ASP.NET page failing?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have the following code

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("user id=clearpath\\user;" +
                                                            "password=Password1;server=sqldatamart;" +
                                                            "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                                            "database=LENDER_LOAN_SERVICE;" +
                                                            "connection timeout=30");


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [LENDER_LOAN_SERVICE].[CMC].[Turn_Times] values('"+dateadded+"','"+username+"','"+prevtime+"','"+type+"','"+newturntime+"')",conn);

    conn.Open();
```

which works fine when I am doing local development.  However when I put the website on my IIS 6 on my computer I get the following error.

```
    Login failed for user 'CLEARPATH\IT-CARLOSDELL$'. 

    Line 42:             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CMC.sp_NewDocMod", conn);
Line 43: 
Line 44:             conn.Open();
Line 45: 
Line 46:             SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

with an error on line 44.

It seems its changing the connection string from clearpath\cpereyra to clearpath\IT-CARLOSDELL$

My computer name is IT-CARLOSDELL

any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What type of authentication does your web site use in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your application pool is using 'LocalSystem' as [pool identity](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).

Answer (score 1):

You need to do one of the following:

1. Give permissions in SQL for the CLEARPATH\IT-CARLOSDELL$ account
2. Change the identity on the application pool to one with permissions in the DB (Perhaps clearpath\cpereyra)
3. Set up authentication on your site to impersonate the user who connected to the site and has rights in the SQL DB.
4. Remove `Trusted_Connection=yes` from your connection string.

Which one you pick depends on the approach you use to secure your site.

BTW: It is not changing the connection string. It is using that account because you have Trusted_Connection=yes. It is using the account the ASP.NET worker process is running under to try to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Trusted_Connection=yes` from your connection string.  Right now, the string is giving a specific user name and password and also saying to use the pass-through Windows authentication.  When running locally, your Windows account has rights to SQL (I assume), but in IIS, it is most likely logging on as anonymous.